# Make control horizontally aligned in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to horizontally align my **UILable** for iPhone screen, by there is no `x` or `left` in mylable properties. 
How can center-align it on the screen?

Comment: In Xcode or in your iPhone app?

Answer (score 1):

The property you are looking for is the `frame` or `center` property.  In this case, `center` is probably your best bet.  All you need to do is something like this:

```
CGPoint newCenter = myLabel.center;
newCenter.x = self.view.center.x;
myLabel.center = newCenter;
```

or

```
myLabel.center = CGPointMake ( self.view.center.x, myLabel.center.y );
```

There are more advanced ways of maintaining center alignment using autolayout, or the autoresizingmask.  If you are interested in learning about them (autolayout being the most robust and in some ways user friendly) I recommend watching the [WWDC 2012 sessions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) about Auto Layout

Comment: myLabel.center.x returns Expression is not assignable

Comment: @Maysam My mistake, I always forget they don't let you access those properties that way, I edited my answer to contain correct code for assigning the center's x component

Answer (score 1):

The best way to determine what types of properties an object has is to use the class reference.  When you first look at [UILabel class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) you'll see there are no properties for adjusting the view of the label.

But if you look at the very top you can see where UILabel inherits from.  You can see it inherits from UIView, which makes sense to look at for what you need since you're asking how to adjust the labels position on the screen (the view).

Click on UIView and you'll be taken directly to [it's reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView).  Scroll down until you see a list of "Tasks" under which there are several categories, each with a number of properties.  You're interested in the "Bounds and Frame Rectangles" category in which there is a property called "frame".

By now we've determined we can set the UILabels frame via myLabel.view.frame

But you may be wondering how to set a frame and so you need to click on 'frame' in the class reference you've been looking at.

You'll see that frame is of type CGRect, so you can use CGRectMake to set the frame.  But now you're asking how do I do that, so we click on the [CGRect reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGRect).

And you can see that CGRect is a struct made of a CGPoint and a CGSize and if necessary please look those up as well to understand how they are defined.

I took this time to explain the flow of using the docs so that you can do it for yourself in the future.  You can survive for awhile on the help of others, but eventually you'll need to just dive into the docs and figure it out for yourself.

In short, you can set the position of your label using the following:

```
myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-someWidth/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2-someHeight/2, someWidth, someHeight);
```

Where someWidth and someHeight are custom variables of float type and self.view is some superview you want to center the label in.

I did not test the code but believe this should work.  Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
mylabel.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), mylabel.center.y);
```